# Camera 2D Movement android unity

Tags: android, camera, unity-game-engine

I'm touching a camera in my android device and it moves with touch but I want to limit its moves in X and Y axis, here is the code that lets me move the camera.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Example : MonoBehaviour
{
public float speed = 0.1F;
void Update() {
    if (Input.touchCount > 0 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Moved) {
        Vector2 touchDeltaPosition = Input.GetTouch(0).deltaPosition;
        transform.Translate(-touchDeltaPosition.x * speed * Time.deltaTime, - touchDeltaPosition.y * speed * Time.deltaTime, 0);
    }
}
}
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Simply clamp the position after movement to stop it.

```
if (Input.touchCount > 0 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Moved) {
  Vector2 touchDeltaPosition = Input.GetTouch(0).deltaPosition;
  transform.Translate(-touchDeltaPosition.x * speed * Time.deltaTime, - touchDeltaPosition.y * speed * Time.deltaTime, 0);

  transform.x = Mathf.Clamp(transform.x, minimumX, maximumX);
  transform.y = Mathf.Clamp(transform.y, minimumY, maximumY);
}
```